# Do I have to annualize daily volatility?

Tags: volatility

I computed daily returns via $\ln(P_t)-\ln(P_{t-1})$ in order to get the volatility. But I do not want to present my results over a certain period of time (whether it's a week, a month or a year). I just want to see the daily variations. Is that meaningful?

Also, in that case, should I still compute the standard deviation? Or is it enough if I present the returns as the volatility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single observation of a return (magnitude) is not a very robust estimate of the volatility. If you're ok with it not being robust then yes, you can use it. Otherwise, the standard deviation is a more robust measure of volatility.

No, you don't need to annualize returns in every situation. For instance, if you're calculating 1-day VaR, the daily return (not annualized) is the relevant metric.